# File access denied while copying data to removable hard drive

Tags: file-permissions

This message is appearing while I am trying to copy my data to removable hdd from PC:
"File Access Denied
You need permission to perform this action
You require permission from 'PC-NAME\USER' to make changes to this file."

I already tried to take ownership of this data but it's not working even after that.

I tried to copy the same data to one of my USB drive which has FAT32 as file system but got same error.

Answer (score 0):

**Hey there!**

Try going to My Computer >>> Click on the drive in question > Right Click and scroll down to Properties >>> Open Properties >>> Click on security tab >>> Check and see if your account has permissions >>> if not then add them.

If you are using a linux system trying changing permissions to 'chmod 777 '.

Let me know if the problem persists ;)

Comment: I tried it on both drives, removable hdd and the drive from which I am copying data. Not worked.

Comment: I am logged in from admin account

Comment: Only one thing comes to my mind which is File Permissions. Which means that the data it self is locked. If you have access to a linux machine or I will try to find a solution ASAP.